# Changing Android's JVM to a LLVM/C backed Compiler to smooth up android like ios

Tags: java, android, c++, jvm, llvm

I was just curious if we can just convert the java byte code into a llvm byte code via a trans-compiler and make a custom android rom where sits a llvm compiler which then compiles the code instead of a jit compiler which is slow.

Will this process speed up android apps loading and all other features as shifting from JVM to LLVM/C backed compiler, thus a compiled app will be generated like ios rather then a Java interpreted app.

Comment: The slowness comes not from interpretation only. And Java VM has JIT anyways.

Comment: Android actually already [does this nowadays](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik#AOT_compilation), and Android N uses a [hybrid AOT-JIT approach](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-the-road-to-jitaot-hybrid-compilation-based-application-user-experience) (JIT apps when used, AOT when device is idle and maybe charging)